# using videoinput from OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, directshow, video-capture

I’m looking for a simple way to use videoinput from OpenCv, because I read a lot of material from the net but still I’m very confused.

I’ve read that from release 2.3 it is part of OpenCv.
What does it mean?

I included “highgui.hpp” and declared “videoInput VI” (with HAVE_DSHOW
HAVE_VIDEOINPUT defined), but got error 'videoInput' not identified.

Then I included a "videoinput.h" file I found in the web and I got 
“error LNK2001: simbolo esterno "public: __thiscall videoInput::~videoInput(void)" (??1videoInput@@QAE@XZ) non risolto”

Have I to download libraries as well?
I thought it should be simpler given that it is “part of OpenCv”.

Comment: if you can't explain *why* you want to use the dshow videoinput code directly, you probably have no reason to do so. look at the answer below, an use the VideCapture class instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and process the video frames I recommend you the VideoCapture class.

Here is an example with an edge detector:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap("videofilename"); // open the video file
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from the video
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My goal is not just retrieving frames from camera, but setting the webcam's properties. I've read (and experienced) that VideoCapture is not always effective for this.